# How increment just year in iso date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have example document

```
{
   _id: ObjectId("59f86bb65264d42f5c2bf758"),  
   startDate: ISODate("2017-10-31T12:30:00.000Z")
}
```

I want to update year in iso date by 2 years with same month and day
How can we achieve this

Didn't find a way to just increment the iso date

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use update with pipeline:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  [
    {$set: {
      startDate: {$dateAdd: {
          startDate: "$startDate",
          unit: "year",
          amount: 2
      }}
    }}
  ]
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xszr2p25P8b)